# iOS Share Extension Obj-C loadItemForTypeIdentifier method always returns an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, appcelerator-titanium, ios8-share-extension

I am creating an app with Share Extension. The sharing works like a charm on Chrome, Safari, and many more, but EXCEPT for PocketApp. If I try to share a link from PocketApp to my ShareExtension App, the hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeURL) function returns true. But during the loadItemForTypeIdentifier, the completionHandler ALWAYS RETURNS an ERROR.

Any thought about this?

```
- (void)didSelectPost{
inputItem = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;

for ( NSItemProvider * itemProvider in inputItem.attachments )
{

    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeURL])
    {
        NSLog(@"Attachment is a URL");
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error occured");
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Success occured");
             }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error is "Unexpected value class."

Comment: What do you get if you make the type of `url` just `id` instead of `NSURL *` in the completion handler?